# Merging rows of many SQLite databases into one

Tags: android, database, sqlite, merge

The question is more like asking for ideas, the scenario is that each android device has its own database.db SQLite file. There can be as many database files as number of devices (getting each database file manually from each device). The Need is to merge/copy rows from all databases and create a master database file.

The more automated the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two option.

> 1. Put all sqlite file in android assets folder and read sqlite table data from assets folder sqlite file and insert it into new master
>      database.

1. Put all sqlite file in android sdcard folder and read sqlite table data from sdcard folder sqlite file and insert it into new master database.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Abdul, lets say i put 20 database under \sdcard\databases\ , how will i go about querying them?

Comment: 1. read list of file in folder then via loop read one by one. it is sample.